# How to notify the user about binding errors in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, exception

To my understanding, binding errors are displayed only during debug mode in Visual Studio's Output window. However, I want to know about broken bindings when the user runs my app, and I want to notify him that something is not working quite right.

Is there a way to handle binding exceptions from code, when the datacontext is set, and some bindings are broken?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to catch all Silverlight binding exceptions in all property setters. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23624349/901333).