# Silverlight exception in ViewModel not caught in Application_UnhandledException

Tags: silverlight, exception, mvvm, unhandled

I have the following situation where an Exception thrown in a ViewModel does not bubble up to the Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs.

I have an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel bound to the ItemSourceProperty in a ComboBox.  The SelectedItemProperty of the ComboBox is bound to a property in the ViewModel.

When the users selects an entry in the ComboBox the property is correctly called in the ViewModel.  A bit of logic is performed and another property (call it property2) is set in the ViewModel.  However, there is an unhandled exception in property2.  The exception just "disappears" - it does not get raised on the UI thread.

Any suggestions for how to generally fix this issue or an approach to catch exceptions on any thread?

Note that we have a custom built MVVM framework.  At first, I thought it was an issue with our framework.  After many hours debugging, I decided to download Prism4 (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=4922) and see if a similar scenario could be reproduced in the StockTrader reference application.

I can reproduce the exact same scenario!  I would be happy to provide details on how to set up the exception in Prism4.

Any help or pointers on a general approach to catch ALL unhandled exceptions in Silverlight is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Travis

Comment: What type of exception is being thrown from your ViewModel?

Comment: Well it may be the browser who might be eating exception in script reporting, normally all exceptions are caught but for that try setting breakpoint in Application_Unhandled method, that will tell you whether it is reaching there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the runtime allows you to use exceptions for validation purposes, the runtime's get-value-for-binding operation is in one big try-catch block.

Take a look at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateValue() in ILSpy for details (in System.Windows.   WPF version may be easier to understand (UpdateSource)).

I don't think its possible to customize the behavior of the runtime to rethrow your own exceptions.  You can see from the code that it does rethrow some critical ones.

```
   OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException, AccessViolationException, ThreadAbortException
```

Since other exceptions are not rethrown, they are, in fact, handled.

I think your solution is to either capture the trace, or have your own exception handling in property setters.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @foson.  In the View I simply subscribed to the BindingValidationError event.  I then put some generalized exception handling in the handler.  FYI ... In order to get this event to fire, one need to set some properties on the Binding.  E.g.,   
_binding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;  
_binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;

Comment: You don't need to add your own exception handling in all property setters or capture (and decode) trace. Recently I found the way how to catch all binding exceptions automatically. See my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found the way how to catch all binding exceptions in all property setters (works in Silverlight 5):

```cs
public class Helper
{
    public static void EnableBindingExceptions(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Static;
        var fields = element.GetType().GetFields(flags).Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty));
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var dp = (DependencyProperty)field.GetValue(null);
            var be = element.GetBindingExpression(dp);
            if (be == null) continue;

            element.SetBinding(dp, new Binding(be.ParentBinding) {ValidatesOnExceptions = true, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = true});
            element.BindingValidationError += OnBindingValidationError;
        }

        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (child == null) continue;

            EnableBindingExceptions(child);
        }
    }

    private static void OnBindingValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new TargetInvocationException(e.Error.Exception);
    }
}
```

Then just invoke EnableBindingExceptions method for every your view:

```cs
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        Helper.EnableBindingExceptions(this);
    }
}
```